# Bracket notation in sets

Tags: notation

I am currently reading a paper on the use of machine learning and was looking at the tuned hyperparameters, when I found the table below.

[Set of hyperparameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI0Ui.png)

I am not sure how to interpret the use of different forms of brackets (round and curly). Does $\lambda \in (10^{-4}, 10^{-1})$ mean that they consider every value inbetween $10^{-4}$ and $10^{-1}$? If so, in which sequence as there is an infinite quantity of numbers between those two.

For the curly brackets I would asumse that for example $LR \in \{0.01, 0.1 \}$ means that they only consider these two numbers $0.01$ and $0.1$.

I came to my conclusion be reading a bit about set theory but I did not find an answer to this specific problem. Does anyone have an idea on how to interpret the use of different brackets?

Comment: Yes, usually $(a,b)$ is an interval (of reals) while $\{ a,b,c, \}$ are discrete values.

Comment: Silly example: $\dfrac 1 2 \in (0,1)$ but $\dfrac 1 2 \notin \{ 0 ,1 \}$

Comment: Thank you very much, that clarifies it I guess!

Comment: You are welcome :-)